# Convert values of two dictionaries to DateTime

Tags: c#

Is there a way to convert string values of two dictionaries to DateTime recursively with only one loop  ( `foreach` for example) ?

(Thanks for the help in advance)

**Check the code below:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{


        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        stopwatch.Start();

        Dictionary<string, string> Dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Dictionary<string, string> Dict2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (var item in Dict)
        {
            foreach (var item2 in Dict2)
            {
                if (item.Key == item2.Key)
                {
                    DateTime date1 = DateTime.Parse(item.Value);
                    DateTime date2 = DateTime.Parse(item2.Value);


                    var diffInSeconds = (date1 - date2).TotalSeconds;
                    Console.WriteLine(diffInSeconds);
                }

            }

        }

        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);

 }
```

Comment: If you want to compare dates why are you storing them as strings? That is very inefficient and opens up all kinds of problems with date formats and localizations. It would really help if you explained where these dates are coming from and why you want to calculate differences.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem, why are the dates as strings, why are they in 2 dictionaries, what decisions lead to this.

Comment: It is very hard to see how you want apply recursion to this code... Some clarification would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

less line of code, an elegant syntax I hope it meets your needs

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        stopwatch.Start();

        Dictionary<string, string> Dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Dictionary<string, string> Dict2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (var item in Dict)
        {
            if (Dict2.TryGetValue(item.Key, out string date))
            {
                var diffInSeconds = (DateTime.Parse(item.Value) - DateTime.Parse(date)).TotalSeconds;
                Console.WriteLine(diffInSeconds);
            }

        }

        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);

    }
```

Comment: "convert string values of two dictionaries to DateTime **recursively**" - I have no idea what OP is trying to achieve but this can't be an answer to the question as there is no recursion whatsoever.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov what is the point of using recursion if you do not need it ?

Comment: How would I know? It is not my question... (I'm somewhat interested in how OP wanted to *recursively* calculate that too :) )

Comment: Thanks everyone, sorry for dumb question

Comment: @anar there is no dumb question , there is question and answer and love coding